# Row Highlighting in hx:dataTableEx

Tags: jsf, hxdatatableex

How can we apply different row colour based on an attribute in hx:dataTableEx.

say for error data that row will be in red.

tried this one but not worked [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014084417)

Comment: It could be achieved with jQuery. Can you use jQuery in your proyect?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. No.That is not possible. Can you advice any other workaround ?

Comment: No, I, m sorry. You should consider use jQuery since it will increase your team productivity.